# Auto save form drafts

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

How does Stack Overflow auto save drafts of this form?  I presume AJAX.  Is there a rails way or gem to use this functionality?

Also, is it actually a separate drafts model or is the form auto created and then from there on out the edit action is being used?

I know I'm asking specifically about Stack Overflow's usage, but, generally speaking.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [Sisyphus.js](http://simsalabim.github.com/sisyphus/) or [Garlic.js](http://garlicjs.org/). While StackOverflow uses AJAX, they use HTML5 localStorage to save form data locally.

Rails gems: [garlicjs-rails](https://github.com/nashby/garlicjs-rails), [sisyphus-rails](https://github.com/dnoonan/sisyphus-rails).

Comment: Just what I was looking for.  For anyone else who finds this:  Sisyphus is older and more mature, Garlic is newer and seems to be getting more recent attention...both do basically the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

First you should get the text that you want to save in database using jquery like this:

```
var text=$("#textToBeSaved").val();
```

then you should make your code to call the server page that would save the text in the database like this:

```
$(".sumButton").click(function()
{
    var text=$("#textToBeSaved").val();
    $.post("pageThatWillSaveToDB.php",{textToBeSaved:text},function(result)
    {
        alert("The Data is Saved");
    }
});
```

and in the page that named `pageThatWillSaveToDB.php` you should do this code:

```
$text=$_POST['textToBeSaved'];
// connectToDatabase();
mysql_query("insert into SomeTable values(null,'{$text}')");
```

Comment: How do you save the id to be edited? session? what if there are multiple tabs @khalidtaha?